# hibernate @Any mapping, can't fetch the "any" item

Tags: hibernate, request, fetch, any

Using hibernate @Any mapping to map multiple entities in the same, I haven't be able to build a request to fetch all the objects of a specific class.

Hibernate doesn't seem to be capable to handle this kind of request.

My application doesn't start and throw the following error :

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.AnyType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.ComponentType
```

removing the part "left join fetch ic.item i" in the request solve this error.

For example, I've got the following model:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "GET_ITEMS", query = "from ItemContainer ic left join fetch ic.item i where ic.id=:containerId and ic.class=:clazz")})
public class ItemContainer {
.... 
    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "TYPE"), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", metaValues = { @MetaValue(targetEntity = Item1.class, value = "I1") })
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_ID")
    private IItem item;
...
}
```

(with Item1 implements IItem)

And here is my DAO :

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<ItemContainer> getItem1s(final Long containerId) {
return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("GET_ITEMS", new String[] { "containerId", "clazz" },
        new Object[] { containerId, Item1.class });
}
```

Is it just impossible, or am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it impossible or did you miss something? I know this was several months ago, but I have the same issue...

Comment: The class is the class name, not the Class object. So it's not new Object[] { containerId, Item1.class }); but new Object[] { containerId, Item1.class.getCanonicalName() });

Comment: Actually it turned out that the class is the descriminator value. So my solution was to check field.class = '<descr>' and field.id = <test id>. In the above case: ic.class = 'I1' and ic.id = etc etc Think I'd better add that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and after much headbanging I discovered that the "class" Hibernate was expecting was a **class identifier**, in this case the **descriminator value**.

So using the above example, the solution was to query the class property as being I1:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<ItemContainer> getItem1s(final Long containerId) {
return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("GET_ITEMS", new String[] { "containerId", "clazz" },
        new Object[] { containerId, "I1" });
}
```

Comment: use the CanonicalName, it's probably the best solution: Item1.class.getCanonicalName()